# Loitering objects Garbage Collection in Java

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I was reading Garbage Collection in Java  and i came across Loitering Objects.

These objects are allocated memory, but not used, and not garbage collected. These keep increasing the size of the JVM heap and represent memory leaks,  which can cause an out-of-memory error or excessive overhead on the garbage collector.

Can anyone please provide a code example for these Loitering Objects.

Comment: Can you please provide *us* an example of those objects?

Comment: Technically, Java doesn't memory leak in the sense a C++ developer would understand. Loitering objects is another way of describing what is referred to as a "memory leak" in Java.

Answer (score 5):

```
public class Cache {
    private static Map<String, Integer> cache = new HashMap<>();

    public static Integer compute(String s) {
        if (cache.containsKey(s) {
            return cache.get(s);
        }
        else {
            Integer result = performComputation(s);
            cache.put(s, result);
            return result;
        }
    }

    private static Integer performComputation(String s) {
        ...
    }
}
```

The above tries to be smart by using a cache of computed values to speed up computation of repeated values. But since old entries are never removed, the cache grows and grows until no memory is available.

Comment: +1 for including an example that actually exhibits the growth problem alluded to in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Following code demonstrates the implementation of Stack using arrays and provides a very simple example of loitering:

```
public class FixedCapacityStackOfStrings {

private String[] array;
private int N = 0;

public FixedCapacityStackOfStrings(int capacity) {
    array = new String[capacity];
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    return N == 0;
}

public void push(String item){
    array[N++] = item;
}

public String pop(){
    return array[--N];
}}
```

Note that while decrementing the value of N in code : array[--N],
it actually shifts the pointer to index at N-1 and index at N points to null.
Here a pointer still points to null even though we know that we are not using it but JVM doesn't know that. Thus causing loitering as this pointer will not be garbage collected by JVM even though it is null.

We can improve this by making the code change as below:

```
public String pop(){
    String s = array[--N];
    array[N] = null;
    return s;
}
```

This version avoids loitering, garbage collector can reclaim memory if no outstanding references.

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Old question but I thought I might clear it up. I originated the term "loitering objects" These are objects that are still referenced by the application but are no longer semantically useful. The difference between a loitering object and a leaking object is that the loitering object will eventually go away. A prime example of loitering are objects attached to HTTP sessions. The Session will time out and the connected objects will go away but in the mean time they will be responsible for all of the problems that come with excessive memory consumption.

With a "normal" memory leak, the leaking object never goes away. This is a bug in your applications logic where as you most likely can technically tune your way out of the loitering situation the only way out of a normal memory leak is to later code.

Though the results of loitering and leaking maybe the same, making a distinction between the two can help in early diagnosis of a problem. Generally you'll have a conversation in which the user will complain about an out of memory error. If the JVM was able to recover from the out of memory error condition than you can be very confident that you have a loitering object. In that case you can look for the use case that breaks the reference holding onto the unneeded data. In most cases that will be a timer. A JVM will never recover from a normal memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

Any object that is reachable from a GC root is ineligible for garbage collection.  GC roots may include static fields, thread-local storage, and any thread's stack.

```
private static Object fieldThatIsNeverAccessed = new VeryLargeObject();
```

Even if the above field is never accessed after initialization, its value, and any objects referenced by that value, directly or indirectly, will remain resident in the heap.